# Restkit - How to map recursive structure

Tags: rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

Given a tree type structure, e.g.:

```
 Folder #1
      Sub-folder #1
           Sub-sub-folder #1
           Sub-sub-folder #2
           ...
           Sub-sub-folder #n
      Sub-folder #2
      Sub-folder #3
      ...
      Sub-folder #n
 Folder #2
      Sub-folder #1
      ...
      Sub-folder #n
```

where any folder (or sub-folder) can have n sub-folders, and those sub-folders can have sub-folders, etc., how can you use RestKit to map this?

I am able to map the first level of sub-folders with the standard RKObjectMapping and relationship mapping, but I can't figure out how to recursively map additional sub-folders (while including each sub-folder's properties - folder id, name, etc.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping that you use for the relationship needs to include a relationship itself. Based on the structure the mapping would be self referential as each lever contains the same contents at the same (relative) key path.

Comment: I understand the concept, can you provide a short example?
I tried adding a referential mapping, but the app crashes because it attempts to keep adding the mapping (circular dependency).